# Windows Task Manager frozen since upgrading to M3.Large instance?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Ever since upgrading my Amazon EC2 instance from an m1.large to an m3.large, task manager is always frozen, to the exact moment when opening it. This is occurring on two separate instances.

[image]

What gives?

Comment: Have you tried the obvious things we do for Windows OS when it freezes - like shut down and restart, reboot, try a different size [ i.e. stop the instance change it to say m3.xlarge or i3.large ] - if nothing works out the last resort would be to take the AMI of those and relaunch it. By the way when you stop the instance put it back to m1.large does it work then ? Worth trying

Comment: - Shut down, restart: yup.
- Difference instance size: nope
- Relaunch AMI: yup

Comment: Almost four years later: this was never resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue today after switching from t2.micro to t2.small

For some reason the Task Manager setting that you can see in the attached screenshot has been changed to 'Paused' during the switch

[image: check out this settings]

Comment: I thought I was losing my mind, but I had the same situation.